# How to draw crystals like in Bejeweled?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, corel-draw

How to draw crystals like in Bejeweled ?
[image]

Is it rendered in 3D and then Photoshop
or vector graphics like Corel Draw

Answer (score 2):

It probably is rendered in a 3D Application, as there are animations (gem's spin/rotate) and to do that by hand for each frame would be tiresome.

I would suggest trying to find some Gemstone shapes as 3D files OBJ, DAE, etc, and then import them into Photoshop CS 6 Extended to handle making the various animation sequences including rotation, spinning, and lighting effects (not Lighting Effects plugin, but animating a light in-front of a gem to make it highlight), using Photoshop's Timeline.

If the gems don't move, then you can build it in Photoshop, but Illustrator would probably be a better choice as it would be easier to create the shapes of the gems.  Cheers and good luck!

P.S., Bejeweled is probably written in OpenGL ES so there is also a possibility that they are using 3D Objects and/or sprite maps/texture atlases for the gems, highlights, explosions, etc...